# django queryset iterator not returning records in action

Tags: python, django, csv

I have the action code as follows for my modeladmin which returns 2 CSV files:

```
def export_csv(modeladmin, request, queryset):

    queryset_f1 = queryset
    response_f1 = export_f1(modeladmin, request, queryset_f1)

    queryset_f2 = queryset
    response_f2 = export_f2(modeladmin, request, queryset_f2)

    return (response_f1,response_f2)
```

Since I need the same queryset objects, for processing each time, I used the iterator as follows:

```
def export_csv(modeladmin, request, queryset):

    queryset_f1 = queryset.iterator()
    response_f1 = export_f1(modeladmin, request, queryset_f1)

    queryset_f2 = queryset.iterator()
    response_f2 = export_f2(modeladmin, request, queryset_f2)

    return (response_f1,response_f2)
```

Now the program is not outputting any results in the 2 CSVs. Why is it so? I am manipulating some objects in export_f1 method which I don't want to change in method export_f2, hence I am using iterator(). If I call the 2 methods separately without using iterator(), they return data in the CSV. I want to return the 2 CSV files simultaneously using this action method in the model admin. How can I achieve this? Using django 1.6.5

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Resolved by calling the iterator in the method definitions instead of the calling method export_csv:

```
def export_f1(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    for obj in queryset.iterator():
         pass
```

Similarly for export_f2, Modified the above export_csv code by removing the iterator call from it to read as:

```
def export_csv(modeladmin, request, queryset):

    queryset_f1 = queryset
    response_f1 = export_f1(modeladmin, request, queryset_f1)

    queryset_f2 = queryset
    response_f2 = export_f2(modeladmin, request, queryset_f2)

    return (response_f1,response_f2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should show some code of your **export_f1** and **export_f2** because when you use an `iterator()` you have *almost* the same as in a **QuerySet** with some differences.

- `iterator()` doesn't cache the query, if you repeat 100 times, django will execute it 100 times
- `iterator()` is good when you have a very big queryset and only need few objects of it
- Using iterator you have to be carefully because it **may be empty** after an operation

To access `iterator()` elements is not the same as a QuerySet, you can access it in different ways. An easy way to generate a full list from the `.iterator()` is:

```
list(queryset.iterator())
```

*If you have `queryset.iterator()` inside a variable called `iter` and you do `list(iter)`, after this instruction **`iter` will be empty***

You can also access objects one by one using `.next()`:

```
# Let's supose you have your iterator in queryset.iterator()
iter = queryset.iterator()
iter.next()  # return first element
iter.next()  # return second element
# After the last element, if you do again iter.next() youll get an exception
```

*If you do `queryset.iterator().next()` will **allways return** the **first element***

But all of this depends on your functions **export_fi** and **export_f2** and how you're using the queryset/iterator. If you show some code of your functions maybe we can find the issue